# log normalizer - exponential family

Tags: calculus, probability, self-learning

i am studying the exponential family- and read that, for $p(x|\mu)=h(x)exp(\eta^T t(x)-a(\eta))$, that $a(\eta)$ is the log normalizer, which ensures that the probability distribution integrates to one. Hence - that as consequence $a(\eta)=\log \int \left(h(x) \exp \eta^T t(x) \right)$. i have tried to set the integral of $p(x|\mu)$ to 1 and derive this implication, but have failed so far. can anyone help me how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$1 = \int h(x)\exp(\eta^T t(x)-a(\eta)) \,dx   $$ then using $\exp(y-z)=\exp(y)\exp(-z)$ $$1 = \int h(x)\exp(\eta^T t(x))\exp(-a(\eta)) \,dx $$ multiplying both sides by $\exp(a(\eta))$ which is  a constant with respect to $x$  $$\exp(a(\eta)) = \int h(x)\exp(\eta^T t(x)) \,dx $$ and taking logarithms $$a(\eta)= \log\left(\int h(x)\exp(\eta^T t(x)) \,dx \right)$$